# Install archlinux package on CentOS 8 or add github repo for auto-updates?

Tags: centos

I would like to install [openvpn-update-systemd-resolved](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/openvpn-update-systemd-resolved/) git link: https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved on my CentOS 8 server. Although I could do as it says in the github repo, just clone and install. I rather add the repo to yum (like I'm used to in ubuntu with apt) so I later get automatic updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursory Google search says no one has ever built this package for RPM based distros, so you cannot use any existing public yum/dnf repos to install/upgrade this package. If you need it for many PCs/servers, you could create your own repository, it's not really hard.

First your write a spec file and build an RPM, e.g. https://opensource.com/article/18/9/how-build-rpm-packages

Then you create your own repo, e.g.: https://github.com/taw00/howto/blob/master/howto-setup-a-local-yum-dnf-repository.md